# Postgres configuration using windows authentication

Tags: postgresql

I'm starting to use Postgres as a database in my application, and I need to configure an agent that serves as a build server as part of the build we are running unit tests.
I need to configure the agent and I'm having trouble as the agent name is different for each machine, and there is a configuration in Postgres that needs to be applied when using windows authentication in the `pg_hba.conf` and `pg_indent.conf`.

In the `pg_indent.conf` I need to use a system user, and I have one, but in the following syntax user@comutername:

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
MapForSSPI     user@computername        postgres
```

The issue is when the agent is starting (we have a dynamic pool) the name of the computer is different, and I want to avoid using the computer name, and use something like `user@localhost` or the equivalent in Postgres.

How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards in [`pg_ident.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-username-maps.html):

```
MapForSSPI     /^user@        postgres
```

That will match everything that starts with `user@`. If the “system user name” starts with a `/`, the rest of the string will be treated as a regular expression.

Please promise me that you will not allow your application to connect as a superuser, that is an unnecessary risk.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and of course, I will take it in attention.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. There should be no brackets around the regular expression, that would change the meaning.

Comment: But it doesn't worked without it.

Comment: Then the system user name does not start with `user@`. `[^user@]` would mean "any string that contains a letter other than `u`, `s`, `e`, `r`, and `@`".

Comment: You're right. There is a Capital Letter in the orig user.